# React Enzyme - simulate multiple clicks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm looking to simulate multiple clicks when testing in React/Jest/Enzyme and then based on what has been clicked test the result. I've tried using `.simulate('click)` however this is used for one Node only, same with using `.prop('onClick)` as well. Is there a way to do this for multiple nodes?

e.g. this is what I have....

```
wrapper.find(Button).at(0).simulate('click');
wrapper.find(Button).at(3).simulate('click');
wrapper.find(Button).at(2).simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.find(Answer).text()).toEqual("23");
```

Hoping to have something like this? ....

```
wrapper.find(Button).at([0, 3, 2]).simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.find(Answer).text()).toEqual("23");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to leverage JavaScript to do it, something like this:

```
const components = Array.from(wrapper.find(Button));
components.forEach(c => c.simulate('click'));
```

To use nodes at specific indexes, modify it slightly.

```
const atNodes = [0, 2, 3];
const components = Array.from(wrapper.find(Button));
atNodes.forEach((c, i) => components[c] && components[c].simulate('click'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This will find all `Button` nodes within the wrapper, where I need to find ones at a specific index number and simulate clicking those particular buttons.